# WHERE clause not showing data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add WHERE clause to filter table data but its showing nothing, its datatable AJAX CRUD project, Any help will be very gratefull
link of full tutorial : https://www.webslesson.info/2017/01/php-pdo-ajax-crud-with-data-tables-and-bootstrap-modals.html

```
$query = '';
    $query .= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 ";
        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
            $query .= 'AND first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
        }
        if(isset($_POST["order"])) {
            $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        } else {
            $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
        }
        if($_POST["length"] != -1) {
            $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
        }
```

if i use below code i am getting all result from table

```
$query = '';
    $query .= "SELECT * FROM users ";
    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
        $query .= 'WHERE first_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    }
    if(isset($_POST["order"])) {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
    } else {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
    }
    if($_POST["length"] != -1) {
        $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }
```

Comment: Here's a familiar Stackoverflow refrain: don't ever put POST data straight into an SQL statement or you will be hacked. Look up MySQL sanitisation, there are thousands of articles ([like https://www.shift8web.ca/2015/06/securing-your-mysql-queries-from-sql-injection-in-php/ or even https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Is there a user with id = 1?

Comment: can you show the complete query after all the values put in?

Comment: Yes @AnuragSrivastava there it is but donno why i unable to get results

Comment: @Jeff here is the link of full article 
https://www.webslesson.info/2017/01/php-pdo-ajax-crud-with-data-tables-and-bootstrap-modals.html

Comment: @JohnCharpata I meant a `echo $query` before you execute it.

Comment: But seeing the link you've posted: Unless you added additional data _manually_ (and followed all the steps in the tutorial), then there is no user with id=1 (auto_increment starts at 74)

Comment: @Jeff no data found after echo

Comment: @Jeff i have tried putting id = 68 but still same problem

Comment: I wanted to see the content of `$query`, the sql string as it is, not any data.

Comment: @Jeff in link there is fetch.php file where i am having issue

Comment: I know. But we still don't know what $query looks like after all the user data was put in, so I cannot really help anymore.